# Would they have enough for the car?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, applications

Gina Wilson and Taylor Baker are roommates employed at Walmart while attending college. Their goal is to buy a car for $\$15,000$ in cash at the end of the year. For that reason, they have put themselves on a strict budget which includes the following:

$40\%$ food and lodging,   $20\%$ entertainment,  $10\%$ education

Gina earns $\$$2,400 per month and Taylor earns $\$1,900$ per month. Carefully show if Gina and Taylor would have enough case to buy the car at the end of the year.

Comment: Don't know about the firm mentioned, but at Mall-Wart wages, to get anywhere near the amounts quoted, neither Gina nor Taylor has time for classes.

Comment: i took 20% 40% and 10% from what they earned..and then multiplied by 12 months but it did not seem right

Comment: Assuming they save the rest, they save $30\%$ of their combined monthly income of $4300$. So take $(12)(4300)(0.30)$. They make it. But can't afford insurance.

Comment: where did the 30% come from

Answer (score 2):

They are using 40% food and lodging, 20% entertainment, 10% education.
So they can save (100-40-20-10=)30% of their combined salary for the car.
Their combined salary is \$2,400 + \$1,900 = \$4,300 per month.
So they will save (30/100)*4,300 = \$1,290 per month.
In a year (of 12 months), they will have saved an amount of 1290*12=\$15,480.
Since this amount is more than the cost of the car (\$15,000), they can have enough cash to buy it.